# Refused to set unsafe header "User-Agent" - Editing WFS layer

Tags: javascript, geoserver, cross-origin-read-blocking

I am trying to create a editable webmap with WFS layer from geoserver. while tring to modify or create features i am mot able to update the feature to the current layer and i am getting the error [Refused to set unsafe header "User-Agent"]

```
var req1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req1.open("POST", url1, false);
    req1.setRequestHeader('User-Agent', 'XMLHTTP/1.0');
    req1.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'text/xml');
    req1.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (req1.readyState != 4) return;
        if (req1.status != 200 && req1.status != 304) {
            alert('HTTP error ' + req1.status);
            return;
        }
```

Comment: you must be using Chromium based browser - switch to using `fetch` instead, or a browser that follows the whatwg spec

Comment: <https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name>